# submitting multiple rows update

Tags: php, mysql

at the top in the php code I am getting the data from the DB:

```
$pricesql="SELECT * FROM my_table";
$pricesqlresult=mysql_query($pricesql);
```

In the body I am having the following in order to list the results

```
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($pricesqlresult)){
$date[]= $rows['date'];
?>
<p><input name="price[]" type="text" value="<? echo $rows['price']; ?>"></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

at the bottom of the page I have a php code with following sql:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$sql1="UPDATE my_table SET price='".$_POST['price'][$i]."' WHERE date='$date[$i]'";
$result99=mysql_query($sql1);
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

I do not know why the code does not update.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can print / echo $sql1 and execute it in MySQL Console?

Comment: What is the value of `$count` ? Did you try to check MySQL errors ? Also, you should give a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php before wasting more time using MySQL_

Comment: $count=mysql_query($pricesql);

Comment: $result99 is undefined

Comment: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in - i am getting these on the because of      $date[]= $rows['date'];

Comment: is the $date getting posted ? do you get any error ? $date is just an array, not any html element, which should get posted

Comment: and moreover if it is getting posted, then use $_POST['date'][$i]

Comment: the price is not getting posted neither '".$_POST['price'][$i]."' , i do not know why

Comment: wait a sec, how are you calling the last code with the update part ? some submit button or something ?

Comment: <input type="image" type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: what ? type = 'image' and also ='submit' ?
and you are postin it on same page ?

Comment: why is that important? if use normal values in update sql it works ok, when i use above mentioned it does not update

Comment: with print($query) i can see that code is executing the UPDATES but the DB is not updated UPDATE my_table SET price = '3' WHERE date = '2013-09-02'UPDATE my_table SET price = '4' WHERE date = '2013-09-03' and so on

Comment: I did the following, but now when the DB is updated, it does accept letters only accept when a number is on the first place:



    $size = count($_POST['datum']);

    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $size) {
        $datum= $_POST['datum'][$i];
        $perso_id= $_POST['perso_id'][$i];
        $schicht= $_POST['schicht'][$i];
        if ($schicht != 0) {
            $query = "UPDATE dienstplan SET schicht = '$schicht' WHERE datum = '$datum' AND         perso_id='$perso_id'";
            mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");

        }
        ++$i;
    }
  }